# Docker Prometheus Config

Tags: docker, prometheus, grafana

I'm trying to configure prometheus and grafana to monitor my django app, but when execute docker-compose up command throws this error:

```
grafana_prometheus_ctnr | level=error ts=2020-10-20T13:08:42.474Z caller=main.go:290 msg="Error loading config (--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml)" err="open /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml: no such file or directory"
```

I have various services one of them is prometheus

docker-compose.yml:

```
...

prometheus:
  container_name: grafana_prometheus_ctnr
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile-prometheus
  volumes:
    - ./prometheus-data:/etc/prometheus
  ports:
    - 9090:9090
  networks:
    - grafana-ntwk

...
```

Dockerfile-prometheus:

```
FROM prom/prometheus:v2.22.0

LABEL version="1.0.0"

COPY ./prometheus.yml /etc/prometheus/
COPY ./prometheus.json /etc/prometheus/file_sd/

EXPOSE 9090
```

prometheus.yml:

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s
  evaluation_interval: 15s
  scrape_timeout: 10s

scrape_configs:
  - file_sd_configs:
    files:
      - /etc/prometheus/file_sd/*.json
```

prometheus.json:

```
[
  {
    "targets": ["0.0.0.0:9090"],
    "labels": {
      "job": "prometheus",
      "environment": "develope",
    }
  },
  {
    "targets": ["0.0.0.0:8000"],
    "labels": {
      "job": "django",
      "environment": "develope",
    }
  },
  {
    "targets": ["0.0.0.0:5432"],
    "labels": {
      "job": "postres",
      "environment": "develope",
    }
  }
]
```

Anybody know why the file is not copied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This update works for me well:

Dockerfile-prometheus:

```
...
COPY ./prometheus.yml /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
COPY ./prometheus.json /etc/prometheus/file_sd/prometheus.json
...
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
...
prometheus:
  container_name: grafana_prometheus_ctnr
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile-prometheus
  volumes:
    - ./prometheus-data:/etc/prometheus
  ports:
    - 9090:9090
  networks:
    - grafana-ntwk
...
```

prometheus.yml:

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s
  evaluation_interval: 15s
  scrape_timeout: 10s

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'monitoring'
    file_sd_configs:
      - files:
        - /etc/prometheus/file_sd/*.json
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is within your `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose` file. The `Dockerfile` copies `prometheus.yml` to `/etc/prometheus` directory. `docker-compose` also mounts volume in the same directory. In such a case the existing files in the directory within the container are masked because the docker mounts them on top of the existing files. The files are still in the container, but they are not reachable. Either remove the `COPY` from Dockerfile or remove volumes from docker-compose or mount them in another directory.